# Find all files from today recursively and copy them

Tags: bash, shell, pdf

I want to find all *.pdf files recursively in directory /dir

In that dir there are specific files such as /dir/1/2.pdf [modified today], /dir/2/3.pdf [modified today], /dir/4/4.pdf [from yesterday]

IN that case I only want files that were modified today so: 2.pdf and 3.pdf

I also want to move those files to directory called /pdf/

I found that I can find all files in current directory modified today with:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1
```

How can I find files from today in subdirectories and move them to /pdf/ dir?

Thanks!!!
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `-maxdepth 1` from your `find` command *to find files in subdirectories* and use `-exec` to move those to the target directory:

```
find /dir -type f -mtime -1 -exec mv {} /pdf \;
```

Comment: how would you preserve the path of the original files and copy those paths recursively ? - Thanks.